# Any way to shrink pagragraph to text without wrapping it into span/div?

Tags: html, css

I frequently find myself doing this:

```
<span>
    <p>hello world</p>
</span>
```

to shrink the paragraph width to the text but it clutters my html. Is there any way to force the `paragraph` element to shrink to text without having to wrap it up in a `span`/`div`?

Comment: Not sure exactlt what you want, but why not just put it in the `span` (i.e., `<span>Hello world!</span>`)

Comment: Paragraph elements should not be inside spans. It's invalid HTML

Comment: @Paulie_D why would it be invalid HTML? Browsers seem to be able to handle it.

Comment: Just because a browser can do it doesn't make it right/valid. Inline elements like spans should not contain block level elements.

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm not saying you're wrong, just would like to know the reason for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to adjust the paragraph width equal to it's content. There are couple of ways.

#### Using `width: fit-content` -

```css
p {
  background-color: pink;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello World</p>
```

#### Using `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` -

```css
p {
  background-color: pink;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello World</p>
```

Comment: `width: fit-content;` was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you